# Php line spacing options for random text

Tags: php, text, random, spacing

Using the code below, I've created a some randomized 'poetry. It gives me a bunch of sentences in 'paragraph' form.

However, I'd like to change up the form to display sentences in stanzas, something more like this: http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/182197 . 'Chrysalis' has stanzas of 1,2 and 2 lines, though I'd be happy to do something simpler (for example, simple three or four line stanzas.)

So I am wondering what code would be best to do this. Or at least which functions might help me in the right direction. Thanks for your input!

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #shape {width: 400px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
echo '<div id = shape>';

$sentences = array (
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur adipisicing elit. ",
"Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam. ",
"Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ",
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate. ",
"Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. ",
"Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. ",
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. ",
"Totam rem aperiam. ",
"Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. ",
"Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit. ",
"Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. ",
"Neque porro quisquam est. ",
"Qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur, adipisci velit. ",
"Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ",
"Ut enim ad minima veniam. ",
"Quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam. ",
"Nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? ",
"Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur. ",
"Vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?",
);

$pick = rand(7,14);
$random_keys = array_rand($sentences, $pick);
shuffle ($random_keys);
$key = 0;
$id = 0;
while ($pick>0) {
echo $sentences[$random_keys[$key]];
$key++;
$pick--;
}

echo '</div>'; //shape
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**COMPLETED CODE:**

Here's the final code I came up with - thanks to Barmar! It includes randomization of the 'line length' and modifies his for-loop to a while-loop.

```
<?php 

$sentences = array (
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur adipisicing elit. ",
"Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. ",
"Ut enim ad minim veniam. ",
"Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ",
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate. ",
"Velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. ",
"Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. ",
"Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. ",
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium. ",
"Totam rem aperiam. ",
"Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. ",
"Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit. ",
"Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. ",
"Neque porro quisquam est. ",
"Qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet. ",
"Consectetur, adipisci velit. ",
"Sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. ",
"Ut enim ad minima veniam. ",
"Quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam. ",
"Nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? ",
"Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur. ",
"Vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? ",
);

$pick = rand(7,14);
shuffle ($sentences);
$key = 0;
$fullstring = '';
while ($key < $pick) 
    { $fullstring .= $sentences[$key];
    $key++; } 

$wrapsize = rand(20, 60);   
$poemtext = wordwrap($fullstring, $wrapsize, "\n");
$lines = explode ("\n", $poemtext);
$count = count($lines);

$stanza_size = 3;
$key = 0; $i = 1;

while ($key < $count) {
    if($i > 0 && $i % $stanza_size == 0) 
    {
    echo $lines[$key]."<br><br>";
    $key++; $i++;
    }
    else {
    echo $lines[$key]."<br>";
    $key++; $i++;
    }
} 

?>
```

Comment: How about inserting line breaks per array value. Something like this: `echo $sentences[$random_keys[$key]]."<br /><br />";`

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't quite produce the same effect - if you look at the poem I linked for example, you'll see that part of the impact comes from the way the line breaks interact irregularly with the sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do evenly-sized stanzas:

```
$stanza_size = 3;
for ($key = 0; $key < $pick; $key++) {
  if ($key > 0 && $key%$stanza_size == 0) {
    echo "<p>";
  }
  echo $sentences[$random_keys[$key]];
}
```

Comment: thanks! it's closer, but not quite. check out my comment to JunM above... the same issue applies, that there is a line break after every sentence. I only want the line breaks between the stanzas, so that the sentences blend into each other in the manner of the poem I linked...

Comment: Changed it. Use `<p>` between stanzas, and nothing between sentences.

Comment: Getting there - the above terminates the stanza after three *sentences*, but those sentences may exceed or fall short of three full *lines*. 

I suspect the solution to this may actually not involve counting the array elements, but rather by limiting the total characters or words per line (such as might involve the `wordwrap()` function), OR by somehow testing for when the html wraps the text inside the div - if such a thing is possible.

(On a side note, what would be the effect of leaving `<p>` tags unclosed?)

Comment: Since line wrapping is dependent on the size of the browser window, that would have to be done in Javascript on the client, not in PHP on the server.

Comment: ah of course - well for the moment scrap that second thought. How about the first?

Comment: Concatenate all the selected sentences, call wordwrap, explode the string on newlines, then use my loop.

Comment: I'll try it! (I'm not sure what you mean by 'newlines' though) ... thanks for your help. I must log off shortly and if so I will let you know how it goes tomorrow.

Comment: Ok - that did it. I have appended the solution to the original post above. Thanks for your assistance!